# Can I still use setTitle when using a custom image for my button in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

Obviously when I use the custom image the text from **setTitle** does not show. Is there any way to still use **setTitle**, or is there another property I can use for text?

func makeButton (vControl: ViewController, action: Selector) {

```
let myButtonImage = UIImage(named: "Picture1.png")
let imageScale = myButtonImage!.size.width / myButtonImage!.size.height
let wwidth = vControl.self.view.bounds.width



let button = CreateButton(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: (myButtonImage?.size.width)!/3, height: (myButtonImage?.size.height)!/3))
button.setImage(myButtonImage, for: .normal)

button.backgroundColor = .clear
button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
button.setTitle("Test Button", for: .normal)
button.addTarget(vControl, action: action, for: .touchUpInside)

vControl.view.addSubview(button)
button.center = vControl.view.center
```

}

[image]

Comment: Can you just show me what output you need?
Image and text both 
So first image and then text right?

Comment: Which image are you trying to set? There is a foreground image and a background image you can set for UIButtons. From the code, the second line is setting the foreground image. If that is your intention, check if you have constrained the button too much that the text got cut off.

Comment: @HetaliBhimjiyani Edited the OP to have the full function I use to make the button, and includes a screenshot. Was hoping I could control text separately

Comment: So by using this: **button.setBackgroundImage(scaledImage, for: .normal)**, it works, does this mean I have to make **setImage** set to nil?

Comment: @LuisC329 If you can show me exactly what output you need then I can help you more in solving your queries.

Comment: @HetaliBhimjiyani You were correct, it works. What I'm asking as a follow up is this:  Is it ok to not assign a UImage only to **button.setBackgroundImage** while not setting one to **button.setImage**?

Comment: @LuisC329 I edited my answer and tried something different check and let me know you need this kind of output or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use image as **Background image**. Then setTitle for set the title. **Here is an example**.

```
let button = UIButton()
view.addSubview(button)
button.setTitleColor(.red, for: .normal)
button.setTitle("Your title name", for: .normal)

button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up"), for: .normal)

// Setting the constraint
button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
button.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor, constant: 200).isActive = true
button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300).isActive = true
```

Comment: Yes this works, as I've said.  But am concerned that am setting the **.setBackgroundImage** yet not **.setImage**. Isn't this sort of like setting it to nil, or is it safe?

Comment: Yes, it is safe & it is not mandatory to use **.setimage**

Answer (score 0):

```
func makeButton (vControl: ViewController) {
    let myButtonImage = UIImage(named: "test.png")

    let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height:100))
    button.setImage(myButtonImage, for: .normal)

    button.backgroundColor = .clear
    button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
    button.setTitle("Test", for: .normal)
    button.imageEdgeInsets.left = -50

    vControl.view.addSubview(button)
    button.center = vControl.view.center
}
```

Try this solution